# RSA 2048 Encryption Decryption skipping special characters

Tags: java, cryptography, base64, rsa

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the data using RSA 2048 with public and private keys.
Everything is working fine except one thing that, the decypted text is coming without some special characters.

I tried various ways of encoding and decoding of Base64 but couldn't find the issue

Comment: Put the code in the question, not on an external site.

Comment: Your code takes Base64, not arbitrary text.  Your problem must be happening elsewhere. Please show us how you're calling it.

Comment: @SLaks added the code which i am using to call

Comment: @kmkaplan just to avoid unnecessary code paste in the thread rather than actual problem, I pasted in other site. sorry for that

Comment: No valid base64 string contains `:` characters. I'm surprised this doesn't throw an exception when you call `Base64.decodeBase64(plainText)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing your class.

Your class takes a **Base64** string, not a string of arbitrary text.

Apparently, the Base64 decoder you're using is silently stripping non-base64 characters rather than throwing an exception.

If you want to use this class with arbitrary text, you'll need to use a Unicode encoding (typically UTF-8) to convert the text into a byte array, then convert that byte array to base64 so that the class can convert it back to a byte array.

I recommend that you change the class to a byte array directly rather than a base64 string; the current design is misleading and pointless.

Comment: sorry. can you please post update of my class.

Comment: @NitinGurram: What part of my answer don't you understand? You need to understand how text and encodings work if you want to work with this.

Comment: Sorry I am newbie to this encoding and decoding.

Comment: I think i tried to understand via wiki and google and updated the code. it's working fine. can you confirm me once whether i have done properly ;)

Comment: @NitinGurram: Your code is now correct.  However, you can avoid the `UnsupportedEncodingException` by passing `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `"UTF-8"`.